# Google consumer survey stats

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, survey, ordinal-data, ranking

In Google's consumer survey product, they calculate confidence intervals using the Wilson score interval for the unweighted results.

Does anyone know how they calculate the confidence interval after weighting? They also state that the "Order is statistically significant". What statistical test do they use for that?

http://www.google.com/insights/consumersurveys/view?survey=qmqopldup5euq&question=1&filter=&rw=1